# How to store information "per browser tab" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC application I have a two pages process. On the first page we gather information that will allow us to identify which database record to update. On the second page we gather new values used to update this record. In order for this to work, we need a way to persists information between the two pages, including some record id.

I though of two way to do this and both have some problem.

1. Store the information in the Session object.

   This works as long as the user does not open a second browser window or tab. If he does there is a risk that he'll apply the modifications to the wrong record. Suppose he opens tab 1 and complete the first step. Record id 1 is stored in the Session object. The user then open tab 2 and complete the first step. Record id 2 is then stored in the Session object overwriting record id 1. The user then come back to the first tab and complete the second step thinking he is editing record 1, but in fact he will be editing record 2.
2. Store the information in an hidden field on the page.

   This would solve the problem solution 1 has, but it would be trivial for a ill-intentioned user to change the record id to overwrite any record.

While typing this question I just though of a third solution. That is an hybrid of theses two, but I'm not sure it's completely safe. We could store a random id in an hidden field on the page and use this to prefix the key we use to access data in the session object. I think this would work. Could this be exploited as solution 2 could?

Any other good way to securely store data "per tab" instead of "per session"?

Answer (score 1):

Considering way 2 you may check security server side. If a user does not have modification rights on a specific record then server must not save it. Otherwise he/she is modifying a record that has modifications rights on it and does not matter if he/she is doing it by standard UI or hacking under it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up two things - authorization and passing data.

If user is authorized to do stuff with "another record", it's not important if he "tempers the hidden", because he is authorized to change another record as well. Nobody is going to do that intentionally. Means - you just need to check if user is authorized to do stuff in every post from the user i.e. in each controller method (and this is normal practice to always validate all user input server-side).

I would suggest you go with "hidden field".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate info in different tabs you should use [`sessionStorage`](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) that differs for each open browser tab.

You can set it like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("perTabValue", "true");
```

Then you can get your value:

```
var x = sessionStorage.getItem("perTabValue");
if(x === "yourValue"){
  //do anithing you want
}
```

Comment: I think I need the information stored server-side, so the user can't temper with it.

Comment: i gess the only way is to sent it via ajax to server. [here is good deep answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796744/1849444).