# How Can i get the value from SessionStorage using JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, class

I developed some code with javascript to retrieve an xhr response and I stored the value in the sessionStorage,

```
var token = xhr.response;
sessionStorage.setItem('Token=', token);
```

Now I need to retrieve this value in my java class. Do you have any idea on how I can retrieve the value of sessionStorage or how to pass the javascript variable in the java class?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

sessionStorage lives only in browser, to make the data available in your server you need to send it to the server. here is a similar question that should explain on how you could do it [HTML5 session storage send to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792158/html5-session-storage-send-to-server).